# Algorithm to calculate sum of LUCKY FACTOR in given range

Tags: c++, algorithm

**Problem Statement :-**

> A number is given, N, which is given in binary notation, and it
>   contains atmost 1000000 bits. You have to calculate the sum of LUCKY
>   FACTOR in range from 1 to N (decimal notation).
>
> Here, LUCKY FACTOR means, (after converting into binary representation) if
>   rightmost or leftmost 1's neighbour is either 0 or nothing(for
>   boundary bit).

**EDITED :-**

> Means if rightmost one's left neighbour is 0, means it count as a
>   LUCKY FACTOR, simlarly in the left side also

**Example,**

```
5 == 101,   LUCKY FACTOR = 2.
7 == 111,   LUCKY FACTOR = 0.
13 == 1101, LUCKY FACTOR = 1.
16 == 1110, LUCKY FACTOR = 0.
0 == 0,     LUCKY FACTOR = 0.
```

**Answer must be in binary form**

**I am totally stuck, give me a hint.**

**My code**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
#include<vector>
//#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

vector<string> pp(10000001);

string add(string a, string b) {
    if(b == "") return a;
    string answer = "";
    int c = 0;
    int szeA = a.size() - 1;
    int szeB = b.size() - 1;

    while(szeA >= 0 || szeB >= 0) {
         answer = (char)( ( ( ( (szeA >= 0) ? (a[szeA] - 48) : 0 ) ^ ( (szeB >= 0) ? (b[szeB] - 48) : 0 ) )  ^ (c) ) + 48 )  + answer;
         c = ( (  ( (szeA >= 0) ? (a[szeA] - 48) : 0 ) & ( (szeB >= 0) ? (b[szeB] - 48) : 0 ) ) | ( ( (szeA >= 0) ? (a[szeA] - 48) : 0 ) & (c) ) | ( ( (szeB >= 0) ? (b[szeB] - 48) : 0 ) & (c) ) );
         szeA--;
         szeB--;
    }
    if(c) answer = '1' + answer;
    return answer;
}

string subtract(string a, string b) {
    int sze = a.size() - b.size();
    while(sze--) b = '0' + b;
    sze = a.size();
    for(int i = 0; i < sze; i++) {
        if(b[i] == '1') b[i] = '0';
        else b[i] = '1';
    }
    if(b[sze-1] == '0') {
        b[sze-1] = '1';
    }
    else {
        int i = sze-1;
        while(i >= 0 && b[i] == '1') {
            b[i] = '0';
            i--;
        }
        if(i >= 0) b[i] = '1';
        else b = '1' + b;
    }
    b = add(a, b);
    b.erase(b.begin() + 0);
    //b[0] = '0';
    while(b[0] == '0') b.erase(b.begin() + 0);
    return b;
}

string power(int index) {
    if(index < 0) return "";
    string answer = "";
    while(index--) {
        answer = '0' + answer;
    }
    answer = '1' + answer;
    return answer;
}

string convert(long long int val) {
    int divisionStore=0;
    int modStore=0;
    string mainVector = "";

    do {
        modStore=val%2;
        val=val/2;
        mainVector = (char)(modStore+48) + mainVector;
    }while(val!=0);
    return mainVector;
}

string increment(string s) {
    int sze = s.size()-1;
    if(s[sze] == '0') {
        s[sze] = '1';
        return s;
    }
    while(sze >= 0 && s[sze] == '1') {
        s[sze] = '0';
        sze--;
    }
    if(sze >= 0) s[sze] = '1';
    else s = '1' + s;
    return s;
}

main() {
    int T;
    char s[1000001];
    string answer;
    scanf("%d", &T);

    for(int t = 1; t <= T; t++) {
        int num;
        answer = "1";
        int bitComeEver = 0;
        int lastBit = 0;
        scanf("%s", s);
        int sze = strlen(s);
        // I used below block because to avoid TLE.
         if(sze > 3300) {
            printf( "Case #%d\n", t);
            for(int i = 0; i < sze; i++) printf("%c", '1');
            printf("\n");
            //continue;
        }
        else {
        if(pp[sze-1] != "") answer = pp[sze-1];
        else {
            pp[sze-1] = power(sze-1);
            answer = pp[sze-1];
        }
        answer = subtract(answer, convert(sze-1));

        ////////////////////////////
        //cout << answer << endl;
        for(int i = 1; i < sze; i++) {

            if(s[i] == '1') {
                if(s[1] == '0') {
                    num = sze-i-1;
                    if(num > 0) {
                        if( pp[num-1] == "") {
                            pp[num-1] = power(num-1);
                        }
                        if(pp[num+1] == "") {
                            pp[num+1] = power(num+1);
                        }
                        answer = add(answer, subtract(pp[num+1], pp[num-1]));
                        if(lastBit) answer = add(answer, "1");
                        //else answer = increment(answer);
                        //cout << "\t\t" << answer << endl;
                    }
                    else{
                        int inc;
                        if(lastBit) inc = 2; //answer = add(answer, "10");
                        else inc = 1; //answer = increment(answer);
                        if(s[i-1] == '0') lastBit = 1;
                        else lastBit = 0;
                        if(lastBit) inc += 2;
                        else inc += 1;

                        if(inc == 2) answer = add(answer, "10");
                        else if(inc == 3) answer = add(answer, "11");
                        else answer = add(answer, "100");
                    }
                }
                else {
                        if(num > 0) {
                            if(pp[num-1] != "") pp[num-1] =  power(num-1);
                                answer = add(answer, pp[num-1]);
                        }
                        else {
                            int inc = 0;
                            if(lastBit) inc = 1; //answer = increment(answer);
                            if(s[i-1] == '0') lastBit = 1;
                            else lastBit = 0;
                            if(lastBit) inc += 1;
                            answer = add(answer, convert(inc));
                        }
                }
                if(s[i-1] == '0') lastBit = 1;
                else lastBit = 0;
            }
        }

        if(s[sze-1] == '0') {
            if(lastBit) {
                if(s[1] == '0') {
                    answer = add(answer, "10");
                }
                else answer = increment(answer);
            }
            else if(s[1] == '0'){
                answer = increment(answer);
            }
        }

        printf( "Case #%d\n", t);
        for(int i = 0; i < sze; i++) printf("%c", answer[i]);
        printf("\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *Here, LUCKY FACTOR means, (after converting into binary representation) if rightmost or leftmost 1's neighbour is either 0 or nothing(for boundary bit).* -- sorry cannot decipher meaning of this sentence...

Comment: Since you only want a hint, it is more of a permutations and combinations problem.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I have brute force logic, but that will fail due to TLE, because of given range of 1000000 bits. So my thinking is blocked beyond that. I just want some intial logic, so that I will start to build my own algorithm.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak Please see the example. Means if rightmost one's left neighbour is 0, means it count as a LUCKY FACTOR, simlarly in the left side also.

Comment: Hint: Calculate the number of numbers of bit length k that have lucky factors of 2 and 1.

Comment: @devsda ok got it :-)

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I didn't get your point, please explain, and yes Time factor is very important, because number of bits in number ranges upto 1000000.

Comment: can u give an example number with lucky factor 3?

Comment: @KeluThatsall Lucky Factor is atmost 2, because you have to consider only leftmost and rightmost 1. The range of Lucky Number is from 0 to 2.

Comment: Do you need to sum lucky factors or the numbers?

Comment: @KeluThatsall only lucky factors, and give the answer in binary form.

Comment: And you assume that a number cannot have leading zeroes, like 00101?

Comment: @KeluThatsall Please help me. I am very near to algo.

Answer (score 1):

If a number has k bits, then calculate the number of such numbers having a LUCKY FACTOR of 2:

10.............01

Hence in this the 1st two and last two digits are fixed, the remaining k-4 digits can have any value. The number of such numbers = `2^(k-4)`.

So you can easily calculate the sum of lucky factors of such numbers = `lucky_factor x 2^(k-4)`
(ofcourse this is assuming k >= 4)

What's more, you do not need to calculate this number since it will be of the form 10000000.

If the number n is 11010010. Then 8 bit numbers less than n shall be of form:
10........ or 1100...... or 1101000_. If you see a pattern, then we have divided the calculation in terms of the number of 1s in the number n

.

I leave the rest for you.

Comment: @Its fine for left most bits, because it start from "1" always, but what about right most ? Example, 1100100. ( Decimal form - 100).

Comment: What Abhishek had in mind was that you can calculate every length in a loop. You can count all the numbers which have 10....01 and multiply it by 2. After that count all the numbers which have 10...0 and add it to the other number. Do it for every length and you get your answer.

Comment: @devsda As an example I have shown for Lucky_Factor of 2. You can build on this idea to get numbers for lucky factors of 1 very easily. For that the numbers shall be of the form 11....01 or 10.....0 or 10......11

Comment: ah yea i forgot to mention them (11...01 and 10...11)

Comment: @AbhishekBansal As your solution said , calculate `2^(k-4)`, but there may chance that it will exceed from given number of k bits, and we have to consider only those number which are less than given number

Comment: @devsda if the given number is of n bits, then you can follow this approach for all numbers having at most n-1 bits. Find the sum of their lucky factors. For numbers with n bits, it is not so difficult to filter out the numbers > the given number.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I got the pattern, if number of n bits is given to us, then, from number having bits number 1 to n-1, we can calculate by using formula = `(2^0 -1) + (2^1 - 1) + (2^2 - 1) + (2^(n-1) - 1) ) == (2^n - n) )`. Now we have to focus only on sum of Lucky numbers having exactly n bits, and smaller than or equal to given number.

Comment: @devsda Yes you are right. A similar approach can be followed.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I got stuck in exactly n bits case.
 Please guide more in this direction.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Can you please start a chat conversation, I will take hardly few minutes, as I have almost wrote my code ?

Comment: @AbhishekBansal I build a code. But it shows Time Limit Exceed. Please help me to make my algorithm efficient.

Comment: @devsda Remember you only required a 'hint'?

Comment: @devsda From your help, I built my whole code, and I think it works fine. I can show that to you also. But it shows Time Limit Exceed.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal So star chat please, I will show that to you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42029/discussion-between-devsda-and-abhishek-bansal)

Comment: @devsda I tried to skim through your code. One mistake that I see is that it seems you are not initializing the vector pp for every test case and hence you maybe using stale data from previous test case. Other than that, the code is not much comprehensible to me, I suggest you use a debugger.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal pp stores power, and that is used by all the test cases. My code works, but it shows TLE. So if you find anything that makes this algo fast, then please tell.